# Extract principal axes in feature space from Kernel PCA in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

There is a subset of gene expression data making 6 feature columns with no target. Using PCA in sklearn, I could separate the 6 features by extracting principal axes in feature space using PCA. Is it possible to plot similar figure using KernelPCA considering components_ attributes does not exist in KernelPCA? Here is my code taken from [here](https://reneshbedre.github.io/blog/pca_3d.html) with small changes.

It is obvious that using KernelPCA(kernel="linear") should lead to the same results as PCA.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA,KernelPCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from bioinfokit.analys import get_data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = get_data('gexp').data
df_st =  StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)
pca_out = PCA().fit(df_st)
loadings = pca_out.components_


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
zz=[]
for i in df.columns.values:
 zz.append(i)
ax[0].scatter(loadings[0],loadings[1])
for i, txt in enumerate(zz):
    ax[0].annotate(zz[i], (loadings[0][i], loadings[1][i]),fontsize=12)
plt.show()

########################## KernelPCA ###################

kpca=KernelPCA(kernel="linear")
kpca_o=kpca.fit(df_st)


#ax[1].scatter(kpca_o[0,:],kpca_o[1,:])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use: `kpca_o.alphas_array`

Source: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html

> alphas_array, (n_samples, n_components)
>
> ```
> Eigenvectors of the centered kernel matrix. If n_components and remove_zero_eig are not set, then all components are stored.
> ```

Comment: kpca_o.alphas produces a matrix with size of (662,6) while loadings = pca_out.components_  is a matrix with size of (6,6)